# How to get the value of HTML5 data-attribute in react js

Tags: html, reactjs, custom-data-attribute, react-dom

```
    <div id="job" data-job-id="3054>jobs status</div>
```

How to get the value of data attribute value in the above node.

Comment: where do you need to get these values?

Comment: Need the data-attribute value in the react entry point file, which should be rendered in the index.html

Answer (score 4):

Just use the javascript .getAttribute() method.

```js
var val = document.getElementById('job').getAttribute('data-job-id');
```

Answer (score 1):

As better solution

```
console.log(e.target.dataset.job-id)
```